# Yii framework renderPartial not working in view

Tags: yii

When I call the `$this->renderPartial()` from a view it is not working at all.

Code I tried:

```
$this->renderPartial("_selectedalbums");
```

the "_selectedalbums" view is in the same directory.

What I am missing, please help.

Comment: What exactly happens? Nothing at all or is there an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are passing values to the view there might be chances that those variables may not be properly assigned or initialized.
Check if all those passing values are getting values. Also turn your error reporting on and see.
Hope it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the partial view is in the same view folder as the controller you are running you should check your spelling. Case sensitive file systems will require you to be exact (`_selectedAlbums` vs `_selectedalbums`).

Comment: Spelling and everything is exact

Comment: remember i am calling this from another view within the same folder

Comment: There must be something minor that's causing this, because it's 100% valid. I vaguely remember something similar when I was working with modules a long time ago. Try `renderPartial('//folder/_selectedalbums')` and see if that helps.